# Fix 'Content wider than screen' on mobile: Can I safely use body overflow-x: hidden?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

When my site is in mobile view I can scroll/swipe the width (x). 
I also got this google mobile usability notification 'content wider than screen'

Can I safely use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 549px) {
    body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

It solves the issue as far as I tested it.

Is there something I have to be aware of? Is this the 'right' solution?

Comment: It'll crop out the content that's wider than the screen which may or may not hinder the experience people have while browsing youe website so, IMO, no that's not a good solution. Check the report details, Google can tell you exactly which page(s) is/are suffering from this so you can inspect them and fix whatever is causing the issue(s).

Comment: I agree with @cabrerahector it's not optimal to go that way. Try to find which element causing the overflow and fix it